# Jquery mobile radio button selection

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement a `horizontal control group` in `jquery mobile` which has radio buttons inside. I am trying to build the HTML string `dynamically` from `code behind`.
These radio buttons are in a for loop .

```
StringBuilder tileString = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);     

foreach (Product product in productsInCart)
        {               
            tileString.Append("<div><legend >Choose shipping type:</legend></div><br />");

            tileString.Append("<input type='radio' name='radio-choice-1' id='radio-choice-1' onclick='findPaymentMethod()' value='In Flight' checked='checked' />");

            tileString.Append("<label for='radio-choice-1'>In flight</label>");

            tileString.Append("<input type='radio' name='radio-choice-1' id='radio-choice-2' value='On Arrival' onclick='findPaymentMethod()' />");

            tileString.Append("<label for='radio-choice-2'>On Arrival</label>");                           
        } `
```

As you can see there is a property on the first radio button.

```
checked='checked'
```

But when this is run in a for loop only the last radio element in the for loop gets checked. Can anyone suggest me whats wrong with the code ? Or am i missing something here ?

**EDIT**: HTML string that gets generated is added .

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain'>
            <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal' id='6' data-mini='true'>
              <div>
                <legend >Choose shipping type:</legend>
              </div>
              <br />
              <input type='radio' name='radio-choice-1' id='radio-choice-16'  value='In Flight' checked='checked'/>
              <label for='radio-choice-16'>In flight</label>
              <input type='radio' name='radio-choice-1' id='radio-choice-26' value='On Arrival'  />
              <label for='radio-choice-26'>On Arrival</label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>`

`<div data-role='fieldcontain'>
            <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal' id='1' data-mini='true'>
              <div>
                <legend >Choose shipping type:</legend>
              </div>
              <br />
              <input type='radio' name='radio-choice-1' id='radio-choice-11'  value='In Flight' checked='checked'/>
              <label for='radio-choice-11'>In flight</label>
              <input type='radio' name='radio-choice-1' id='radio-choice-21' value='On Arrival'  />
              <label for='radio-choice-21'>On Arrival</label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
```

Only 1 radio element is getting checked within the `fieldset`

[Here's an image of the desired effect](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnqek52rs0j0y62/Stackoverflow.PNG).

Comment: Can you also add a HTML output to your question?

Comment: @Gajotres - Thanks for the reply . Added the HTML output.

Comment: From what I can see first element is checked: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8BGEq/

Comment: @Gajotres - Your html works fine since you have only one control group. But when i try to add multile control groups dynamically from a for loop only the last listitem element gets checked . Added an image also for reference

Comment: Can you check one more thing, are you sure checkboxes inside every group have unique id? I think they all have same id attribute and because of that you have this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AFVLK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your name attribute (like id one) must be unique.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SBxVc/

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain'>
     <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal' id='6' data-mini='true'>
         <div>
             <legend >Choose shipping type:</legend>
         </div>
         <br />
         <input type='radio' name='radio-choice-16' id='radio-choice-16'  value='In Flight' checked='checked'/>
         <label for='radio-choice-16'>In flight</label>
         <input type='radio' name='radio-choice-26' id='radio-choice-26' value='On Arrival'  />
         <label for='radio-choice-26'>On Arrival</label>
     </fieldset>
</div>

<div data-role='fieldcontain'>
    <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal' id='1' data-mini='true'>
        <div>
            <legend >Choose shipping type:</legend>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type='radio' name='radio-choice-11' id='radio-choice-11'  value='In Flight' checked='checked'/>
        <label for='radio-choice-11'>In flight</label>
        <input type='radio' name='radio-choice-21' id='radio-choice-21' value='On Arrival'  />
        <label for='radio-choice-21'>On Arrival</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```