# Radiobuttonlist visually allows multiple selections and locks to first selection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery-mobile

I have a page on a website that takes a few choices from a user. Since the website is dedicated to mobile users, I'm using JQuery Mobile. The website is also managed by a CMS, which means I need to generate pages from code-behind files written in VB.net.

Now for every choice the user needs to make, there's a `collapsible` I make inside a collective `collapsible-set`. For some choices, a radiobuttonlist is generated. Generating the radiobuttons is done through a repeater that goes through all possible picks and generates a radiobutton per option. When the user then presses the button to confirm his choices, the chosen options are collected and sent to the server for processing.

Now, I've tried my best to adjust the repeater  and the code-behind to generate the necessary tags and attributes to allow JQuery Mobile to set up it's layout, but that has caused the generated radiobuttonlists to no longer work as they should.
Whenever the page is loaded, it automatically checks the first option, and locks it to said option. Visually, on the other hand, one can actually select all options in the entire radiobutton list (no options are deselected when you select another). This is only visual (in reality, only the very first selection ever is checked behind the scenes and does not change when trying to select others).

I've tried a few things left and right regarding the list. I've put a `field-set` tag around the repeater to bind all the generated radiobuttons together, and have altered the code in order to make sure the `name` attributes are unique (the ID is already unique). Here's a quick link to one of the questions I've checked. Not directly relevant to my problem, but I thought it might be solved by following the answer: [Jquery mobile radio button selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039072/jquery-mobile-radio-button-selection) .

Here's how the HTML looks for one of the radiobutton lists in the component (pre-CMS-generation):

```
<div class="detailblock thumbs" runat="server" id="div_plants" data-role="collapsible">
    <asp:Literal ID="litTitle_plants" runat="server" />            
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <asp:Repeater ID="repDetails_plants" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="litValue" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radPlant" runat="server" GroupName="plant" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

First there's the `collapsible` that contains all the options for plants. The first literal is used to set the title of the `collapsible`. Then we have the `field-set` that is supposed to bind the radiobuttons together. Finally, we have the repeater that generates an invisible value per plant, and a radiobutton.

Here's the code that handles the generation of every single item:

```
Protected Function ProcessProductPlant(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) As Boolean
    Dim plant As em_clsProductSizeColorPlant = e.Item.DataItem

    If plant Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If

    Dim litValue As Literal = e.Item.FindControl("litValue")
    litValue.Text = plant.id

    Dim radPlant As RadioButton = e.Item.FindControl("radPlant")
    If Not plant.Image Is Nothing Then
        radPlant.Text = "<img src='" & plant.Image.ToLower & "' alt='" & plant.description & "' />"
    Else
        radPlant.Text = "<img src='" & "/websites/1/uploads/img/wapla/logo.jpg" & "' alt='" & plant.description & "' />"
    End If
    radPlant.Attributes.Add("name", "plant_choice_" & e.Item.ItemIndex)

    If e.Item.ItemIndex = 0 Then
        radPlant.Checked = True
        litCurrentPlantId.Text = "var currentPlantId = '" & plant.id & "';"
    End If

    radPlant.Attributes.Add("onclick", "currentPlantId = '" & plant.id & "'; change_image();")

    Return True
End Function
```

Finally, here's how the plant-collapsible looks HTML-wise when generated:

```
<div id="ctl24_div_plants" class="detailblock thumbs" data-role="collapsible">
        <h2>1. choose a plant</h2>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> 
            <span name="plant_choice_0"><input id="ctl24_repDetails_plants_ctl00_radPlant" type="radio" name="ctl24$repDetails_plants$ctl00$plant" value="radPlant" checked="checked"/><label for="ctl24_repDetails_plants_ctl00_radPlant"><img src='/websites/1/uploads/image/productimages/filrouge/plants/jpg/cycas_thumb.jpg' alt='BUSINESS 01' /></label></span>
            <span name="plant_choice_1"><input id="ctl24_repDetails_plants_ctl01_radPlant" type="radio" name="ctl24$repDetails_plants$ctl01$plant" value="radPlant" /><label for="ctl24_repDetails_plants_ctl01_radPlant"><img src='/websites/1/uploads/image/productimages/filrouge/plants/jpg/sanseveria_kirkii_thumb.jpg' alt='BUSINESS 01' /></label></span>
            <span name="plant_choice_2"><input id="ctl24_repDetails_plants_ctl02_radPlant" type="radio" name="ctl24$repDetails_plants$ctl02$plant" value="radPlant" /><label for="ctl24_repDetails_plants_ctl02_radPlant"><img src='/websites/1/uploads/image/productimages/filrouge/plants/jpg/zamioculcas_thumb.jpg' alt='BUSINESS 01' /></label></span>        
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Note how one item is already checked. In reality, one could SEE all 3 plants checked, while the HTML will keep ONLY THE FIRST SELECTION checked.

If any of you need more information to help me, feel free to ask. All help is welcome.

**EDIT**

I've picked up somewhere that the groupname for all radiobuttons need to be the same. In the `ItemTemplate`, I've already set the groupname, but don't see it anywhere in the generated HTML. Do I need to set the groupname through code, or is the groupname not supposed to be visible in the generated HTML?

**EDIT2**

I've tried fixing the radiobuttons by forcing a refresh on the radiobuttons, suspecting the initial selection-setting might break the lay-out. I've used the following piece of JQuery-script in the HTML document itself to do the refreshes (colorchoices is the second set of radiobuttons on the page):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("fieldset[id='plantchoices']").children("input").each("refresh");
    $("fieldset[id='colorchoices']").children("input").each("refresh");
});
```

Note: this piece of script did NOT solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I've managed to achieve what I wanted by attaching the following piece of JavaScript on the `onmouseup` attribute of each radiobutton:

```
function uncheck_others(radiobuttonId) {

        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('input').attr('checked', false);
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).attr('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('label').removeClass('ui-radio-on');
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('label').children().children().removeClass('ui-icon-radio-on');
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('label').addClass('ui-radio-off');
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('label').children().children().addClass('ui-icon-radio-off');
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('label[for=' + radiobuttonId + ']').removeClass('ui-radio-off');
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('label[for=' + radiobuttonId + ']').children().children().removeClass('ui-icon-radio-on');
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('label[for=' + radiobuttonId + ']').addClass('ui-radio-on');
        $('#' + radiobuttonId).parent().parent().parent().children().children().children('label[for=' + radiobuttonId + ']').children().children().addClass('ui-icon-radio-off');
    }
```

I realise this script is highly impractical, unreadable and there are likely much more efficient takes on this problem. I am leaving this script here for future references either way.

I'd still like to note that this script must be attached to the `onmouseup` event and not the `onmouseclick` event in my specific case. Attaching it on the `onmouseup` event resulted in JQuery reverting my JS changes to the broken locked formats as mentioned earlier.